# What is the difference between a let block statement and an equivalent with statement?

Tags: javascript, language-features, with-statement, let, ecmascript-6

> ## *OBSOLETE*
>
> The block version of the let statement was dropped from ES6 before it was finalized, and it has been removed from the browsers that supported it. This question is now only of historic interest.

Is there any difference between using an [ECMAScript 6 `let` block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_blocks) and  using a `with` statement with an equivalent object literal?

#### using `let` statement

```
var x = 10;
let (x = x * 10,
     y = x + 5) {
    console.log("x is " + x + ", y is " + y);
}
```

#### using `with` statement

```
var x = 10;
with ({x: x * 10,
       y: x + 5}) {
    console.log("x is " + x + ", y is " + y);
    // writes "x is 100, y is 15"
}
```

Comment: Is the question for entertainment, or are you seriously considering using `with` for scoping?

Comment: If the answer was conclusively "no difference" then I would consider it, but I was mainly curious because I expected a difference but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best I can come up with is that `with` will also leak any property of the `Object` prototype:

```
with ({x: 10}) {
    hasOwnProperty = 3;
    console.log(hasOwnProperty);  // 3
}
console.log(hasOwnProperty);  // [native code]; this is window.hasOwnProperty
```

Unlikely to be a problem in practice, but still a potential gotcha.

I also suspect that `with` is slightly slower than lexicals, since it adds another namespace that has to be searched.

Honestly, I'd just avoid both constructs; `with`-style implicit property access doesn't sit well with me, and if I really need a tight scope like that, a bare block with `let` expressions inside reads less awkwardly than a `let` block.

Comment: Note that ECMAScript 5 lets us create an objet with no prototype as `Object.create(null)`, so it actually seems possible to use this with no side-effects. However, ES5's strict mode disables `with`, so this is only possible in ES5's default mode and won't be possible in ES6.

Comment: See [Was there a way to create an object without a prototype prior to ES5?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36117912/1114) for a possible (though very impractical) alternative for ES3.

Answer (score 8):

You can use both `with` and `let` statements to achieve the same goal but I see two significant differences here. In the end, the `let` statement is a new revision of the `with` statement with the disadvantages of the latter removed.

**Performance**: In case of the `with` statement you add an additional JavaScript object to the scope chain. This isn't a small cost, you have to remember that objects have a potentially long prototype chain and so to look up a variable the JavaScript engine first has to search the object and all its prototypes. On the other hand, for a `let` statement the engine only needs to search at most one additional object. The `let` statement can indeed be implemented without any overhead at all, since all the variables declared in a `let` statement are known at compile time and the JavaScript engine can easily optimize the code, e.g. by essentially treating your example like:

```
var x = 10;
var let1x = x * 10;
var let1y = x + 5;
{
    console.log("x is " + let1x + ", y is " + let1y);
}
```

**Code readability**: As already mentioned above, a `let` statement always makes all declarations visible at compile time, this prevents code like this:

```
with (foo)
{
    console.log("x is " + x + ", y is " + y);
}
```

If you look at the code above, what is `x` and what is `y`? Are they function variables or properties of the object `foo`? You cannot tell it without knowing what `foo` is - and it might be different for different calls of the same function. Which is the main reason the `with` statement has been deprecated. While you can use it the way you've done in your question (and that is fine), it also allows very questionable and unreadable code constructs. The `let` statement doesn't - less flexibility is sometimes an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the different scoping rules for each statement.

with:

> the with statement makes access to named references inefficient, because the scopes for such access cannot be computed until runtime

let:

> The scope of variables defined using let is the let block itself, as well as any inner blocks contained inside it, unless those blocks define variables by the same names.

The `let` statement is non-standard, while the `with` statement is unavailable in Strict Mode.

**References**

- [ECMA-327:ECMAScript 3rd Edition Compact Profile](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/Ecma-327.pdf) (pdf)
- [Resurrecting the with Statement](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2013/01/resurrecting-with-statement.html)
- [ECMAScript Harmony: Object Extension Literal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:object_literals#object_extension_literal)
- [let: block scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Block_scoping)
- [ECMAScript-6 Draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html)