# Was there a way to create an object without a prototype prior to ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

Was there a way to create an object without a prototype prior to ES5?

i.e. something like `Object.create(null)` (ES5)

I thought something like this might work, but the final statement  unexpectedly returns `true`:

```
function withPrototype(p) {
  function temp(){}
  temp.prototype = p;
  return new temp();
}

Object.getPrototypeOf(withPrototype(null)) === Object.prototype; // true
```

`Object.getPrototypeOf` is ES5. I use it here for exposition.

Comment: the polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill says you just need `Temp.prototype = null;`

Comment: No. Before ES5, the only object (possibly excluding host objects and the global object) with [[Prototype]]=null is `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Oriol has shown, there was no "official" (spec-compliant) way to do this.

However, there was indeed an object that had no prototype - `Object.prototype` itself.

> #### 15.2.4 Properties of the Object Prototype Object
>
> The value of the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the Object prototype object is `null` and the value of the internal `[[Class]]` property is `"Object"`.

You could potentially "create" such an object by instantiating a new environment ("realm" in ES6 terms), e.g. via an `<iframe>`, capturing its `Object.prototype`, stripping it of its properties and voilá - you've got a new empty object.

```
function getNoProtoObject(callback) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.onload = function() {
    var obj = iframe.contentWindow.Object.prototype;
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);

    // Remove all built-in enumerable properties.
    for (var name in obj) {
      delete obj[name];
    }

    // Remove known built-in non-enumerable properties, which may vary.
    delete obj['constructor'];
    delete obj['hasOwnProperty'];
    delete obj['isPrototypeOf'];
    delete obj['propertyIsEnumerable'];
    delete obj['toLocaleString'];
    delete obj['toString'];
    delete obj['toSource'];
    delete obj['valueOf'];
    delete obj['watch'];
    delete obj['unwatch'];
    delete obj['__defineGetter__'];
    delete obj['__defineSetter__'];
    delete obj['__lookupGetter__'];
    delete obj['__lookupSetter__'];
    delete obj['__proto__'];

    callback(obj);
  };
  iframe.src = 'about:blank';
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

getNoProtoObject(function(o) {
  console.log(o);                        // Object {  }
  console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(o)); // null
  console.log(o.__proto__);              // undefined
});
```

Comment: Although Oriol's answer contained the most useful information for me, this answer it would seem, is the ultimate answer.

Comment: What is spec non-compliant about this approach?

Comment: @BenAston: ES3 does know nothing about iframes. It's a DOM API, not an ES one - and you can always have an ES implementation with host objects that do whatever they want, of course, so nothing is "impossible" :-)

Comment: The problem could be if some implementation added extra own non-enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` (not sure if this would violate the spec). Even if configurable, it would be difficult to delete them due to the non-enumerability and lack of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Comment: @Oriol: Very true, but I guess such behaviour would at least have been documented somewhere :-) The whole approach works only in specific environments anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I found this idea extremely clever and interesting, and needed to check it out for myself. Cheers!

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I'm glad you got it working, I've never tried it myself and feared someone would dispute me :-)

Comment: You can do it synchronously: `var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); document.body.appendChild(iframe); var obj = iframe.contentWindow.Object.prototype; document.body.removeChild(iframe);`

Answer (score 2):

No. Searching `[[Prototype]]` in the [ES3 spec](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) shows that the only way of changing [[Prototype]] to an arbitrary given value is through [[Construct]].

However, it only works if that value is an object. If it's not (including `null`), the [[Prototype]] will be set to the initial value of `Object.prototype`.

> **13.2.2 [[Construct]]**
>
> When the [[Construct]] property for a Function object F is called, the
> following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Create a new native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set the [[Class]] property of Result(1) to `"Object"`.
> 3. Get the value of the `prototype` property of the F.
> 4. If Result(3) is an object, set the [[Prototype]] property of Result(1) to Result(3).
> 5. If Result(3) is not an object, set the [[Prototype]] property of Result(1) to the original Object prototype object as described in
>    15.2.3.1.
> 6. Invoke the [[Call]] property of F, providing Result(1) as the **this** value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as the argument values.
> 7. If Type(Result(6)) is Object then return Result(6).
> 8. Return Result(1).

Comment: So the polyfill at MDN cannot work for `null` then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill

Comment: @BenAston Yes, it can't work for `null`. Instead of the buggy `typeof prototype != 'object'`, which filters out callable objects and doesn't filter out null, the polyfill should check `Object(prototype) === prototype`. That's the reliable way to check if something is an object.

Comment: @BenAston: Oh my, someone [missed the reason and threw it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create$compare?to=648525&from=644991)

Comment: Note: They might have used `typeof` hoping it would filter out host objects, because it was implementation-dependent whether they were supported in [[Prototype]]. But the result of `typeof hostObject` is implementation-dependent, so there is no guarantee they would be filtered out. `Object(prototype) === prototype` won't filter them out.

Comment: So an improvement to the polyfill would be to reinstate the `null` check, with a comment indicating that this is a limitation of pre-ES5 implementations, not present in ES5's `Object.create`?

Comment: @BenAston I would use something like `if(Object(prototype) !== prototype && prototype !== null) throw new TypeError('Argument must be an object or null'); if(prototype === null) throw new TypeError('null is not supported');`. Or maybe Error instead of TypeError in the 2nd check.

Comment: I have submitted a change on the MDN page to incorporate a null check with a similar error message to your suggestion.

Comment: But `Object(undefined) !== undefined`

Comment: Your reasoning is that because typeof does not actually filter anything out, we may as well use `Object(prototype) === prototype`? The benefit being is doesnt mislead?

Comment: @BenAston The problem with `typeof` is that callable objects are objects, but `typeof` says `"function"`. `Object(prototype) === prototype` is a better way to test if something is an object. So the polyfill throws an error if you pass a callable object, but it would be able to handle that case properly.

Comment: Ah, ok, of course. I'll make an edit to the MDN page.